# How to a create a child thread or worker thread in Microsoft bot application

Tags: botframework

[Microsoft bot builder sdk]
How to a create a child thread or worker thread in Microsoft bot application which can continuously listen to a third party Web APi and post to users on different connectors.

I created a bot and want that bot to listen to a third party Web API continuously. This work should be done in a separate thread. But if I create a thread in a Dialog class it does not post responses to user as dialog object gets suspended as it wait for user input.

```
[Serializable]
public class SampleDialog : IDialog<object>
{
    protected int count = 1;
    [NonSerialized]
    Thread ChildTask;
    public async Task StartAsync(IDialogContext context)
    {           
        ChildTask = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(RunChildTask));
        ChildTask.Start(context);
        context.Wait(MessageReceivedAsync);
    }

    private void RunChildTask(object context)
    {
        IDialogContext contex = context as IDialogContext;
        while (true)
        {
            this.count++;
            contex.PostAsync($"{this.count++}: You said From child");
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
    }

    public virtual async Task MessageReceivedAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> argument)
    {
        var message = await argument;
        if (message.Text == "reset")
        {
            PromptDialog.Confirm(
                context,
                AfterResetAsync,
                "Are you sure you want to reset the count?",
                "Didn't get that!",
                promptStyle: PromptStyle.None);
        }
        else
        {
            await context.PostAsync($"{this.count++}: You said {message.Text}");
            context.Wait(MessageReceivedAsync);
        }
    }
```

RunChildTask method is called but does not post back to user.

Answer (score 0):

The reason it isn't working is because of the nature of the technology that the chatbot is implemented in. Chatbots use ASP.NET Web API, which like all other Web applications (e.g. WebForms or MVC) is stateless. That means that a request arrives from the client (the Bot Connector in this case), the request is processed by your chatbot, the chatbot responds, and the class instance for the chatbot becomes eligible for garbage collection. When the next request comes in, it creates another Web API instance for your chatbot.

Since the class instance no longer has references, neither do the services. The thread you just started no longer has a valid reference to the services. Therefore, you have a race condition where the normal processing of the chatbot finishes before the thread you started can successfully execute. Because it's a race condition, there might be times when the thread gets lucky and posts a message, which would probably be confusing when it works only sometimes. For this type of task, you should consider a more durable implementation like a cloud service or windows service on a VM.